# using HTML5 Canvas - rotate image about arbitrary point

Tags: html, canvas, html5-animation

Rotate the dial on top of a semi circular(Northern Hemisphere) image as background.
range could be 0 - 180 degrees.
on input to the method that does canvas transformation, the dial would rotate and stop over the matched value.
Here's what I was trying based on help and sample passed on by [phrogz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405017/phrogz)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Canvas rotate from bottom center image angle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365382/canvas-rotate-from-bottom-center-image-angle)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In general, what you want to do is:

1. Transform the context to the point on the canvas that the object should rotate about.
2. Rotate the context.
3. Transform the context by the negative offset within the object for the center of rotation.
4. Draw the object at 0,0.

In code:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate( canvasRotationCenterX, canvasRotationCenterY );
ctx.rotate( rotationAmountInRadians );
ctx.translate( -objectRotationCenterX, -objectRotationCenterY );
ctx.drawImage( myImageOrCanvas, 0, 0 );
ctx.restore();
```

Here's a [working example](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_gauge.html) showing this in action. (The math for the rotation was just experimentally hacked to find a swing amount and offset in radians that fit the quickly-sketched gauge dial.)

As may be evident, you can substitute the `translate` call in step #3 above with offsets to the `drawImage()` call. For example:

```
ctx.drawImage( myImageOrCanvas, -objectRotationCenterX, -objectRotationCenterY );
```

Using context translation is recommended when you have multiple objects to draw at the same location.

Comment: Thanks for quick help and the Demo too. :)

Comment: For further discussion, see this (duplicate) question and answer: [HTML5 Canvas `drawImage` at an angle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793397/html5-canvas-drawimage-with-at-an-angle).

Comment: Still stuck when it comes to replacing the parameters in rotate() method to incorporate feed from data structure.

Comment: @Ab Perhaps you are receiving degrees and passing them to `rotate()` without first converting them to radians? If so, multiply by `Math.PI/180`. If that doesn't help, edit your question with a pared-down test case showing your actual code and we can move forward from there.

Comment: Many Thanks, I'm almost there :)

Comment: Thanks, been looking to do this for hours now :-)