# dynamic speedmeter javascript or jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

[image]

I want to have **dynamic ajax plugin** to show a speedmeter on the page.
One Idea is that I set a background and rotate the needle.
Anyone knows about a related plugin?

Comment: Why do you want it to be a plugin?

Comment: It's obvious. why should I implement it, when a plugin exists?

Comment: Hey Dariush, you might want to check [this](http://joncom.be/code/css-clocks/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some for your reference

http://bernii.github.com/gauge.js/

https://github.com/vjt/canvas-speedometer

And lots of more at [Drawing a half gauge/speedometer (JavaScript Canvas or Java Swing Example needed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083221/drawing-a-half-gauge-speedometer-javascript-canvas-or-java-swing-example-needed)