# can we generate Gauge charts using canvas tags....?

Tags: javascript

As Part of my project we have generated **GAUGE CHARTS** dynamically using svg tag..
Here im adding the url for  dojo Gauge charts documentation which we have used:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/gauges/GlossyCircularGauge.html

My Question is can we generate this Gauge charts using canvas tags....?

I'm new to this svg and cancas..

Can anyone help me?

Comment: yes you can do that in canvas tag.

Comment: I'm new to this gauge charts.."can you please tell me how to do this using canvas? Add any simple example....?

Answer (score 0):

Go to following link. You will surely get your answer.
[Drawing a half gauge/speedometer (JavaScript Canvas or Java Swing Example needed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083221/drawing-a-half-gauge-speedometer-javascript-canvas-or-java-swing-example-needed)

Another hands on example link:
http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/make-gauge-charts-using-canvas-and-javascript