# Rotating a png image about its bottom center from within a .js file

Tags: javascript, image, png, rotation, image-rotation

First of all, let me quickly explain why I brought this up despite similar question here:
[Canvas rotate from bottom center image angle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365382/canvas-rotate-from-bottom-center-image-angle)

All the information I have seen so far is concerned with javascript embedded in html markup. I do not know whether this information would suffice for someone more experienced than I, but I know very little javascript and html. I do have a little experience in a lot of scripting languages however.

My problem is that I have a .js file that takes an object, i, and sets i.image to a png image from a url (say example.com/pic.png). I want to add a few lines of code that first rotates the image by x degrees or radians (I do not care which, I can always convert) first, then sets it to i.image. So:
image="example.com/pic.png";
i.image=MagicRotateFunction(image,45);

I just have no idea what MagicRotateFunction would be.

Comment: Where does your javascript run, if not on a HTML page in the browser? Do you use Node.js (serverside) or WSH?

Comment: the easiest way is for you to checkout css transfomations, using the rotate function: check an example here http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate

Comment: Node.js (serverside) I think. I am editing a .js file and uploading it up to the server. I really do not know from what file(s) the html markup is being generated. It is a file that makes a google maps map and I want to rotate the markers so I can display several markers on the same location.

Comment: As for the css transformations, how do I go about embedding this in a .js file? I am trying to limit the file I have to edit to that .js file because I think tracking down the mechanism of transforming an icon into a marker on a google map on a wiki site would be a lot more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested in doing CSS transformations in a .js file, try this:

```
i.src = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png";
i.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(45deg)";
i.style.MozTransform = "rotate(45deg)";
i.style.OTransform = "rotate(45deg)";
i.style.msTransform = "rotate(45deg)";
i.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";
```

Sources:

- [How to set the style -webkit-transform dynamically using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708895/how-to-set-the-style-webkit-transform-dynamically-using-javascript)
- http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html